# Loading selected shapefile from dropdown in Leaflet map having PostgreSQL database using GeoDjango

Tags: leaflet, postgresql, geodjango

My base.html looks like this

```
{% load static %}
<!--To load leaflet links-->
{% load leaflet_tags%}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Interactive Map - Leaflet JS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <!--Leaflet js and css links respectively, no need to add manaul links as we already installed django-leaflet-->
  {% leaflet_js%}
  {% leaflet_css%}
  <!--To load shapefile from database-->
  <script src="{% static 'leaflet.ajax.js' %}"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="{% url 'district' %}"  method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <select id="district_sel"  name="chooseDistrict">
    <option disabled='true' selected>Choose district</option>
    {% for result in showdis%}
    <option value={{result.district}}>{{result.district}}</option>
    <!--here district is column name'district' stored in database-->
    {% endfor%}
  </select>
</form>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    let mymap = L.map('map', {
      center: [28.394, 84.1240],  
      zoom: 7                     
    });
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>', //osm tile layer and copyright are generated
      maxZoom: 18,
      id: 'mapbox.streets',

    }).addTo(mymap);

    $( "#district_sel" ).change(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'district' %}",
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: "text",
      data : {
        filter_category:  $('#district_sel').val(),
        action:'get'
},

      success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          
          var datasets = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'district' %}",{ //where district is name for shapefile datasets
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            }
          });
         
          datasets.addTo(mymap);
  
      }
  });
     });
   
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.db.models import Manager as GeoManager

class District(models.Model):
    objectid = models.BigIntegerField()
    province = models.BigIntegerField()
    pr_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.district
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include 
from .views import index,district_datasets,showdis
from django.urls import path
from .models import firsttest

urlpatterns= [
    path('ab', index.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    path('district_data', district_datasets, name="district"),   #Shows district data into geojson format
    path('', showdis, name="dist"),
]
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import firsttest,District
from.forms import DistrictForm
#Shows directly homepage
class index(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'index.html'
      
def district_datasets(request):
    selected_value = request.GET.get('filter_category')  
    Districts = serialize('geojson', District.objects.filter(district=selected_value))
    return HttpResponse(Districts,content_type='json')

def showdis(request):
     results=District.objects.all().order_by("district")              #gives in ascending order
     return render(request,'index.html',{"showdis":results})
```

Comment: Please edit your question (which at the moment just a bunch of code) and describe in more detail what you want to achieve, what have you tried so far and where are you stuck.

Comment: Through this code, selected shapefile from dropdown should have loaded on leaflet map but it doesn't happen

Comment: Can you try to print the `selected_value` in views.py? That will let you know whether ajax request is working fine or not.

Comment: @Tekson selected value is printed while trying to print selected_value in views.py